# Syntax "cellule.utilisateurs.all" does work in a Django HTML template, but not in a Django TeX template

Tags: python, django, tex

The syntax "cellule.utilisateurs.all" does work with an HTML Django template, but does not work with a TeX Django template.

With the HTML Django templates, it displays in the resulting HTML file displayd in the WEB browser the list of users ("utilisateurs" in French) of each cell ("cellule" in French).

With the TeX Django template, I get the following error message in the WEB browser:

'method' object is not iterable

Here are the different pieces of code:

**HTML template**:

```
<html charset="UTF-8">
    <body>
        <p style="font-size:40px;color:blue">INFOREFLEX_GENER_HTML_CELLULES, version 1.0 (23/07/2019)</p>
        <p style="font-size:30px;color:red">(Date de l'import des données en base : {{ dateDernierExport }})</p>
        {% for cellule in listeCellules %}
        <a id="{{ cellule.dpt_im }}"></a>
        <h1 style="font-size:60px;color:blue">{{ cellule.dpt_im }}</h1>
            <table border="1">
                {% for utilisateur in cellule.utilisateurs.all %}
                <tr>
                    <td style="background-color:moccasin;font-weight: bold"><a href="http://annuaire-entreprise.inetpsa.com/?action=exec_recherche_personne&identifiant={{ utilisateur.cod_user }}" target="_blank">{{ utilisateur.cod_user }}</a>-{{ utilisateur.lib_prenom }} {{ utilisateur.lib_nom_usuel }}</td>
                </tr>
                {% endfor %}
            </table>
        {% endfor %}
    </body>
</html>
```

**TeX template**:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{color, colortbl}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[margin=0.25in]{geometry}

\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=blue,
    filecolor=magenta,      
    urlcolor=cyan,
}

\title{INFOREFLEX_GENER_HTML_CELLULES, version 1.0 (23/07/2019)}
\author{OPEN Emmanuel Duvshani}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

% \maketitle
\bigskip
(Date de l'import des données en base :\VAR{dateDernierExport})
\bigskip
\newcolumntype{y}{>{\columncolor{yellow}}l}

%% for cellule in listeCellules
    \hypertarget{\VAR{cellule.dpt_im}}{\VAR{cellule.dpt_im }}
    \bigskip
    \begin{flushleft}
    \begin{tabular}{ | y | }
    \hline
    %% for utilisateur in cellule.utilisateurs.all
        \hyperlink{http://annuaire-entreprise.inetpsa.com/?action=exec_recherche_personne&identifiant=\VAR{utilisateur.cod_user}}{\VAR{utilisateur.cod_user}}-\VAR{utilisateur.lib_prenom}\VAR{utilisateur.lib_nom_usuel}
        \hline
    %% endfor
    \end{tabular}
    \end{flushleft}
    \bigskip
%% endfor

\end{document}
```

**Function run in the "views.py" file**

**When using the HTML template:**

```
enter code here

def index_cellules(request):

    # Date de dernier export de la base Reflex
    listeDateExports = DateExports.objects.all()
    dateDernierExport = listeDateExports[0].date[:10]

    # Liste des applications de la table Perimetre
    listeApplications = Perimetre.objects.values_list('hdkqtap').all()

    # Liste des cellules correspondant aux applications de la table Perimetre
    listeCellules = Hdkqtif.objects.filter(hdkqtap__in=listeApplications).distinct().order_by('dpt_im')

    template = loader.get_template('inforeflex_gener_html/index_cellules.html')

    contexte = {
        "dateDernierExport" : dateDernierExport,
        "listeCellules" : listeCellules,
    }

    return HttpResponse(template.render(contexte))
```

**When using the TeX template (with jinja):**

```
def index_cellules(request):

# Date de dernier export de la base Reflex
listeDateExports = DateExports.objects.all()
dateDernierExport = listeDateExports[0].date[:10]

# Liste des applications de la table Perimetre
listeApplications = Perimetre.objects.values_list('hdkqtap').all()

# Liste des cellules correspondant aux applications de la table Perimetre
listeCellules = Hdkqtif.objects.filter(hdkqtap__in=listeApplications).distinct().order_by('dpt_im')

latex_jinja_env = jinja2.Environment(
     block_start_string = '\BLOCK{',
     block_end_string = '}',
     variable_start_string = '\VAR{',
     variable_end_string = '}',
     comment_start_string = '\#{',
     comment_end_string = '}',
     line_statement_prefix = '%%',
     line_comment_prefix = '%#',
     trim_blocks = True,
     autoescape = False,
     loader = jinja2.FileSystemLoader('C:\\EMMANUEL\\inforeflex\\django\\inforeflex\\inforeflex\\templates\\inforeflex_gener_html')
)

template = latex_jinja_env.get_template('index_cellules.tex')

contexte = {
    "dateDernierExport" : dateDernierExport,
    "listeCellules" : listeCellules,
}

return template.render(dateDernierExport=dateDernierExport, listeCellules=listeCellules)
```

The **expected results** are, for each cell, the formatted list of users.
The **actual result** is an error message concerning the line "    %% for utilisateur in cellule.utilisateurs.all". This is the complete error message:

`
*TypeError at /inforeflex_gener_html/cellules

'method' object is not iterable

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/inforeflex_gener_html/cellules
Django Version:     2.2.2
Exception Type:     TypeError
Exception Value:

'method' object is not iterable

Exception Location:     C:\EMMANUEL\inforeflex\django\inforeflex\inforeflex\templates\inforeflex_gener_html\index_cellules.tex in top-level template code, line 42
Python Executable:  C:\Users\edu04718\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe
Python Version:     3.7.3
Python Path:

['C:\EMMANUEL\inforeflex\django\inforeflex',
 'C:\Users\edu04718\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python37.zip',
 'C:\Users\edu04718\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\DLLs',
 'C:\Users\edu04718\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib',
 'C:\Users\edu04718\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32',
 'C:\Users\edu04718\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages']

Server time:    Thu, 19 Sep 2019 15:19:47 +0000*
`

**Remark**: Line 42 is the following line in the TeX template:

```
%% for utilisateur in cellule.utilisateurs.all
```

Comment: In jinja, you need to actually call the method: `for utilisateur in cellule.utilisateurs.all()`. The error you see is just saying that the `all` method isn't iterable.

Comment: Yes, with the syntax cellule.utilisateurs.all(), it does work. Thank you very much for your help.